# How to send canvas image large size from silverlight to WCF service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I have a large size byte[] formed from silverlight Canvas using following code

```
var img = new WriteableBitmap(cnvControlHolder, null);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        EncodeJpeg(img, outStream);
```

Now I want to send this to WCF service to form image from this byte array & save it as an image on server side so that I can consume it in SSRS. My problem is as the byte[] is big I get the classic Method not found from WCF service.

I read in few links that WCF streaming would be one option, but could not find any sample on the net. My service method is like this:

```
public bool Upload(Stream image)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        BinaryWriter writer = null;
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + @"\" +
                           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PictureUploadDirectory"] + @"\Diagram.jpeg";// +image.ImageName;
            if (image!=null)
            {
                //return ByteArrayToFile(filePath, image.Imagestream);
                fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
                writer.Write("Diagram.jpeg");
            }
            return false;
        }

and client call is this :

var img = new WriteableBitmap(canvas1, null);
var outStream = new MemoryStream();
EncodeJpeg(img, outStream); //custom library to compress into jpeg
var client = new Service1Client();
client.UploadCompleted += new EventHandler<UploadCompletedEventArgs>(client_UploadCompleted);
client.UploadAsync(outStream.ToArray());
```

Can somebody suggest some sample or any other solution to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a very similar solution in Silverlight. The solution involves:

- Dividing the large byte[] into n chunks of size that can be sent via a web service call
- Making a web call to the service, registering a file upload request for n chunks, and requesting a guid from the service.
- Making n web calls to the service and uploading each chunk, supplying the guid and the ordinal of the chunk (the chunks may arrive out of sequence).
- Once the server receives all n chunks, it combines the chunks and writes the data into a file.

I hope this can help to get you started.

Comment: Thanks @Boluc. Can't we use streaming because that will do the job of merging the chunks & we don't need to worry about checksum etc.